# Angular 5 - How to create Single Service instance in an hierarchical architecture?

Tags: rxjs, observable, angular5

I created BaseService, CommonService as below and my other services are dependent on this hierarchy. My main intention was to reuse the utilService and cacheService in all my ModuleServices [there are many ModuleServices].

```
export abstract class BaseService {
  public utilService: UtilService;
  _listingSubject = new ReplaySubject();
  public listingObservable: Observable<QuickList> = this._listingSubject .asObservable();
  constructor() {
  super();
    this.utilService = ServiceLocator.injector.get(UtilService);
  }
}

export class CommonService extends BaseService {
  public cacheService: CacheService;
  constructor() {
  super();
    this.cacheService = ServiceLocator.injector.get(CacheService);
  }
}

export class ModuleServiceA extends CommonService {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

> I declared my services under Providers list in AppModule - haven't
>   injected at component level

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [CommonService, ModuleServiceA..]
  ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I couldn't inject directly in constructor as below which would then mandate all child services are also declared with all arguments. Which I wanted to avoid.

```
constructor(public cacheService: CacheService)
```

However, with above hierarchical architecture, as am calling super() constructor in every child Service, a new instance of BaseService/CommonService is created - defeating the base purpose.

> Also, the Observable am creating in BaseService [listingObservable]
>   is not unique anymore and my subscribers in components and other
>   places are not being notified at all.

---

Please can someone advise how can I use hierarchical architecture but still have one instance of each service created!

Comment: That would be the expected behaviour with using inheritance... Why do you want to avoid passing the dependencies in the constructors?

Comment: Have you thought about having your Observable be a private static variable to share the same observable across all instances and have a public getter to get the value as if it were an instance property?

Comment: try create decorator for service.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel l I tried private as below but it didn't work either

_listingSubject = new ReplaySubject();
public listingObservable: Observable<QuickList> = this._listingSubject.asObservable();

Comment: Did you try is as a static property?

Comment: @FanCheung Have fallen back to constructor injection for now. Let me try Decorators as well

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel sorry didn't notice 'static'. Thanks it worked!